# Is sqlite db file available under any platform?

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

For example, can I generate a SQLite db file and put it as a resource in the project. When the project first launches, copy the db into isolated storage without worrying this db file may be unavailable in the phone. Furthermore, can I copy this empty db file into another platform, like android or iPhone, and operate this db by in SQLite api of the platform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [SQLite web site:](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html)

> A database in SQLite is a single disk file. Furthermore, the file format is cross-platform. A database that is created on one machine can be copied and used on a different machine with a different architecture. SQLite databases are portable across 32-bit and 64-bit machines and between big-endian and little-endian architectures.

So yes, when you've validated that the SQLite API is available everywhere you want to use it, that should be fine as a storage format.

EDIT: And yes, [SQLite does work on Windows Phone 7](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx), using [this Codeplex project](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/releases) or [this one](http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Yes agree with your sentence, but this is not an exact solution for implementing existing SQLite database in Windows phone 7 app.

Comment: @Bhuro: It was more addressing the last part about portability.

Comment: @Bhuro: Now added a link to a guide to using SQLite on WP7.

Comment: @JonSkeet you know i have just started with WP7 development, so please  support my newbie questions. Actually i just want to copy SQLite file while running app for the 1st time and use it later. I have SQLite database file ready which i have used earlier in Android/BB.

Comment: @Bhuro, you could have just commented on this answer, and got your answer. There was no need of bounty.

Comment: @Bhuro, you can view the link provided by `theChrisKent`. It does help.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will try example link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  We are using the same SQLite database in an iOS, Android and WP7 app.  I've written a quick start guide here: http://wirebear.com/blog/2010/11/12/using-sqlite-in-your-wp7-app

The above blog post covers copying your database from your resources to isolated storage and correctly configuring SQLite to work on your device.

Comment: Thank you. What you said is that we want to do in next project. Thank you for the blog you gave.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite version is compatible with Android - iOS - WindowsPhone  as far I have experimented. I have created SQLite DB on a Mac Desktop and copied it into projects along with data into each of these platforms. Everything worked fine no issues.

Ref:

http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

> **Precompiled Binaries for Windows Phone 8**
>
> sqlite-wp80-winrt-3071502.vsix (2.72 MiB)
>
> A complete VSIX package with an extension SDK and all other components
>   needed to use SQLite for application development with Visual Studio
>   2012 targeting Windows Phone 8.0. (sha1:
>   4cab3fd698402bf30448c64e39001103c10ff82b)

The download page itself lists the entire code and binaries for different platforms. Using a PC/Mac for creating a DB is convenient option.

You can use SQLite manager for doing so on a Windows or Linux PC.

SQLite Manager (Preferred by Myself)

http://sqliteman.com/

There are also extensions for Chrome and Firefox, which makes SQLite Available for almost any platform to Manage them.

Firefox Plugin for managing those files.
https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

codev.it also allows to enable editing SQLite Files.

As far as DB is concerned, Exporting them from the device is as described by @Jon Skeet

SQLite 3.7 is more compatible with Windows Phone. Since SQLite DBs are backward compatible, there isn't any need to worry weather your DB works on older 2.x version or 3.x..

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not looking for a SQLite database creating task but a code/example/procedure to use existing SQLite database in WP7 app. Could you please help me for it if possible?

Comment: @PareshMayani When you include the SQLite Pre-compiled Binary you can use the DB in your application. See the sample implementation and reference in the SQLite Website.

Comment: @PareshMayani GoTo Tools-> Extensions and Updates 

Search for sqlite. You will find sqlite for windows phone.. A blue icon. After that you can use it as normal sqlite DB.

Comment: here is the link for the msdn library.. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cd120b42-30f4-446e-8287-45387a4f40b7

Comment: If you still got problems here is a github proj.. https://github.com/peterhuene/sqlite-net-wp8

Answer (score 0):

@Bhuro As you want a detailed procedure for using SQLite db in a Windows Phone 7 app, Here is a good post [Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx).

I have successfully followed the same process in my WP app. Try that and let me know if you get any doubt.

Good luck !!

Comment: Thanks for sharing but please check, Jon Skeet has already provided this resource.

Comment: Ooops I didn't check. Then what is the problem you faced with this approach ? Did you try that ?